# Is there a standard web-based font that is similar to Malgun (Korean font)?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, frontend

A client **needs** to have [Malgun](http://fonts.cloffin.com/details.php?font=Malgun%20Gothic%20Bold) as the font whenever hangul characters are present. I'm trying to find something to use in CSS that is close to it. I was thinking Verdana. Anyone else have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "standard web-based fonts", only fonts that are more or less probable to be installed on the computer, where the browser is running. You may try to build a font-stack, that comes close to the one you want, e.g. the Verdana based font stack from [this Sitepoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/eight-definitive-font-stacks-2/), and then use font-loading methods like Google Webfonts to load your defined font for browsers that support loading fonts.

Do not try to give each visitor the same experience, but the best experience possible. Tell your customer, that a website is not a application that looks the same everywhere, but more like a TV program, that must be viewable from a black and white TV also, see [this video](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/03/video-progressive-enhancement-2-0/).

Answer (score 1):

Verdana is also looking closer to Malgun, I think you should try google fonts http://www.google.com/webfonts

Comment: I've looked at googles webfonts but can't really find one I'm happy with

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [Fontsquirrel @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) ? Also, for hangul, you might be interested in [reading this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#unicode-range-desc).